# sql server pivot of row values into columns

Tags: sql-server

[Please click to see image of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Iyr.jpg) Source data 
dept    val_y
x1      val1
x1      val2
x1      val3
x1      val4
x1      val5
x2      val7
x2      val8
x2      val9

I want it transformed into

dept    val_x1  val_x2  val_x3  val_x4  val_x5  val_x6  val_x7  val_x8  val_x9
x1      val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    null    null    null    null
x2      val7    val8    val9    null    null    null    null    null    null

So if I have another department with N rows, columns val_x1 to val_xN will be populated with value from column val_y, and columns val_xN+1 to val_x9 will be null (assuming N<9).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: searched for pivot?

Comment: Please click link above to see image of source data and after transform.

Comment: @Kannan..yes i searched for pivot but the answers don't give me what I need. Or maybe I don;t fully understand the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot as below:

```
Select dept, [1] as Val_x1, [2] as Val_x2, [3] as Val_x3, [4] as Val_x4, [5] as Val_x5 from 
( Select dept, val_y, RowN = Row_Number() over (partition by dept order by val_y) from #data1 ) a
pivot (max(val_y) for RowN in([1],[2],[3],[4],[5] --...yourlist of columns
)) p
```

Output as below:

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| dept | Val_x1 | Val_x2 | Val_x3 | Val_x4 | Val_x5 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| x1   | val1   | val2   | val3   | val4   | val5   |
| x2   | val7   | val8   | val9   | NULL   | NULL   |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks...that's a lot closer.
But I want the val_y values transformed in the order they appear on the table source.
For example, if val2 comes before val1 for dept x1 then Val_x1 should have val2.

Comment: In that case you need to have ordering column from source table like id, or date

Comment: SQL Server generates %%LockRes%% which is some sort of row number.
How can I use this to order?

Comment: you can use that in RowN = Row_Number() over( partition by dept order by yourcolumn)...

Comment: If %%LockRes%% is column name then you need to provide that in square brackets as [%%LockRes%%]

Comment: Thanks Kannan for the assist. I have a solution!